# Short include paths in bazel C/C++ project

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I'm new to using `bazel` and I don't know how to make the path of my includes not have to be a full path. You can see the comment in `src/main/main.c` file.

My directory tree:

```
.
├── WORKSPACE
├── src
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── BUILD
│   │   └── mytypes.h
│   └── main
│       ├── BUILD
│       └── main.c
└── test
    └── BUILD
```

`src/lib/mytypes.h` file:

```
#ifndef MYTYPES_H
#define MYTYPES_H

typedef unsigned char byte_t;

#endif
```

`src/lib/BUILD`file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "mytypes",
    #srcs = glob(["*.c"]),
    hdrs = glob(["*.h"]),
    visibility = ["//src/main:__pkg__"],
)
```

`src/main/main.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "src/lib/mytypes.h"  // I would like to use: #include "mytypes.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    byte_t byte = 0xAF;
    printf("%X\n", byte);
    return 0;
}
```

`src/main/BUILD` file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "mytypes",
    #srcs = glob(["*.c"]),
    hdrs = glob(["*.h"]),
    visibility = ["//src/main:__pkg__"],
)
```

`WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "com_google_googletest",
    sha256 = "7b100bb68db8df1060e178c495f3cbe941c9b058",
    strip_prefix = "googletest-release-1.11.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.11.0.tar.gz"],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cc_library.includes](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.includes) is what you're looking for. Change your `src/lib/BUILD` contents to:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "mytypes",
    includes = ["."],
    hdrs = glob(["*.h"]),
    visibility = ["//src/main:__pkg__"],
)
```

Comment: It works! Than you. But, now I have a problem with Visual Studio Code because lint give me an error in the include statements. Do you know if there is any way to configure vscode to work with bazel together?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BazelBuild.vscode-bazel is the only thing I've seen for vscode, I've never used it. If you want help setting that up, try asking another question so somebody with knowledge there can see it.